# Jupyter notebook not opening from anaconda for Mac Segmentation fault 11

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, navigator

I am dealing with some trouble with the anaconda navigator. It wouldn't update spyder so I tried to delete it and reinstall it but then now the whole thing doesn't work and jupyter notebook would not open at all. Below is the message I receive from the terminal when I click on jupyter notebook.
Can anybody help me with this?

Last login: Sat Jul 15 15:43:08 on ttys000
(base) macadminui-MacBook-Pro:~ macadmin$ /anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 5: 13695 Segmentation fault: 11  $DIR/jupyter-notebook
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

I tried to uninstall Anaconda as suggested on the website using terminal but failed to get rid of it completely and so tried reinstalling it but keep on getting error message that the install failed. The navigator still opens but gives the Segmentation fault 11 for both jupyter notebook and spyder.